# Is there any command-line function which will return the name of the main class from a huge Java file?

Tags: java, automation

I want to automate the process of downloading a huge number of Java files from the internet and test them one by one. However, most of the sites do not specify the name of the main class. Therefore, most of the time, I need to manually search for the string "public class" in order to determine the filename. Is there a better process to do it?

In general, the code format is:

```
import ...
import ...
import ...

class A {...}
class B {...}
public class C {...}
```

Comment: And what actually makes you think that if a class is public then it means it's actually the main class? I think you should search for the main method instead with smth like `grep "public static void main" *.java`

Comment: I would recommend you use `grep`.

Comment: @funkyjelly Yea, I agree. But, is there any inbuilt function to do the same?

Comment: No I don't think so. If you have just raw source code files your best chance is with text searching tools like `grep` I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -lP '\s*public\s+static\s+void\s+main\s*\(\s*(?:\[\s*\]\s*)?String\s*(?:\[\s*\])?\s*\w+\s*\)' *.java
```

The above command will return a list of .java files containing a main method, which is just an indication of being the Main class for each program.

As said above, a public class does not necessarily means it is the main class of a program, so the above grep command is your best chance in this case I believe.

Please also note that within the same app/program there could be more than one classes containing a main method, even though only one is actually used as the program's entry point.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is pretty close. However please change line to:
`grep -lP '\s*public\s+static\s+void\s+main\s*\(\s*(?:\[\s*\]\s*)?String\s*(?:\[\s*\])?\s*\w+\s*\)' *.java`
This lists all the file names, from which the '.java' can be subtracted. That will do.

Comment: Many thanks @TreffnonX for the suggestion. Excellent point to treat extra spaces between words and various ordering. Not sure for the downvote but my guess is it was form the other answerer :)

Comment: @Paul that's true however earlier you mentioned the "Java specification" conventions, while now you pick up a very extreme case which would make the OP's task impossible to solve as he'd need to search for smth that doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Paul I never claimed that my answer solves all cases. I rather mentioned it as "best chance" to achieve what the OP needed, and also highlighted possible pitfalls.